# How to set font-family and font-size for TextArea with Vaadin CssLayout?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Is there documentation about it? How can I get a `TextArea` with Monospace 10px for displaying log output, without resorting to css stylesheet classes? I mean using the `getCss(Component)` method of `CssLayout` instead of `addStyleName` of `TextArea`.

I found that (at least) these properties seem to be silently ignored by Vaadin `CssLayout`:

- width
- height
- font-family
- font-size

UPDATE/SOLVED: Thank you guys for your help. Turns out that I forgot a semicolon somewhere between style statements. Vaadin then never pushed that faulty CSS to the DOM. Which made it difficult to debug for me.

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting to clear cache in your browser?

Comment: Check your browsers devtools to get a clear picture, of what styles are there and in what order they are appliied.  Is your change overridden by a more accurate rule?